# Reading Mail Content Using Java Mail API

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am able to get the from field and subject field correctly , But i am getting the Mail Content in Object Format even though i m using toString() method..

please check with the following source code

```
    try {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        Store store = session.getStore();
        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "mymail@gmail.com", "****");
        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message msg = inbox.getMessage(inbox.getMessageCount());
        Address[] in = msg.getFrom();
        for (Address address : in) {
            System.out.println("FROM:" + address.toString());
        }

        Object obj = msg.getContent();
        //Multipart mp = (Multipart)obj;

        Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
       // MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart)mp.getBodyPart(0);
        BodyPart bp = ((Multipart) msg.getContent()).getBodyPart(0);

        // Object body = msg.getContent();

        //String value = String.valueOf(body);

        System.out.println("SENT DATE:" + msg.getSentDate());
        System.out.println("SUBJECT:" + msg.getSubject());
        System.out.println("CONTENT:" + bp.getContent().toString());
    } catch (Exception mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

```
    output console:

   FROM:Myname <mymail@gmail.com>
   SENT DATE:Tue Nov 05 12:28:24 IST 2013
   SUBJECT:test
  CONTENT:javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@5117f31e
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to iterate through all multiparts, then check `MIME` type of the `Part` in order to know if you have to treat it like a text or an attachment.

```
for(int i=0;i<multipart.getCount();i++) {
    BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
    if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/*")) {
        String s = (String) bodyPart.getContent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`bp.getContent().toString()`

will give you mail body only when your mail is not multipart(ie if your mail is multipart mail then it will not work)