# Java mail get only typed content

Tags: java, email, metadata

I'm have a java mail message receiver from a gmail address. When I get **javax.mail.Message** from **text/html** type I can get the typed content only but when is a MultiPart message give me an **HTML** with a lot of metadata.

How can I extract only the typed content of a message in java mail?

Other problem is that the metadata change from each mailer that was sended

I'm already extract the message using some like this

```
            Object o = e.getContent();
            if (o instanceof Multipart) {
                Multipart mp = (Multipart)o;
                System.out.println("Text: ");         
                for (int j = 0; j < mp.getCount(); j++) {
                    BodyPart b = mp.getBodyPart(j);
                    if (b.getContentType().contains("multipart")) {
                        mp = (Multipart)b.getContent();
                        j = -1;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if(!b.getContentType().contains("text/html")) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Object o2 = b.getContent();
                    if (o2 instanceof String) {
                        System.out.println(o2);                 
                    }
                }
            }
```

But the output doesn't useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784271/reading-mail-content-using-java-mail-api

Comment: You need to iterate all multiparts and read only if MIME type is text.

Comment: I already got the message from iteration, but gives me an HTML with metadata that doesn't care to me, I want to extract only the typed content of an e-mail.

Comment: What is the MIME type?

Comment: multipart/alternative